# Hadoop client JDK compatibility for communicating with Cloudera cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, client, java-8, version

At the moment, we have both our Hadoop cluster (CDH 4.1.2) and services that communicate with it via hadoop-client running Java 6. We're planning to move those client components to Java 8 leaving Hadoop servers running on top of Java 6 as they do now because Cloudera has declared support for JDK 8 only since version 5.3.0, and we're not planning to upgrade Hadoop - details here:
https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_rn_new_in_530.html
Therefore, our concern is whether different versions of Java in cluster (6) and in client components (8) may lead to problems of any kind. Internet hasn't been of big help as long as Hadoop compatibility with Java is mainly discussed regarding migration of server components, so please share your experience relevant to this matter if you have one.

Comment: I would recommend simply testing it. I believe pre-configured virtual machine images are available, so just setup a few VMs on a beefy workstation and try it out?